# Adding selected class to a gallery item (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, css

I am listing bunch of galleries on a page like this.

[image]
.

I need jQuery code to check the URL and based on that add a selected class to the tab item whether chicago weddings or tented weddings... and at the same time add a selected class to the gallery item so I can style its background differently.

Here is a sample code for one gallery tab:

```
<span class="carousel-link" data-tabid="carousel1">CHICAGO WEDDINGS</span>
```

Here is a sample code for one gallery item:

```
<figure id="attachment_11004" style="width: 180px;" class="wp-caption alignnone">
    <a title="Destination Weddings - Anguilla" href="/gallery/destination-weddings/anguilla.html">
        <img class="galleryImg alignleft size-full wp-image-11004" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/destination-weddings-anguilla.jpg" alt="Destination Weddings - Anguilla" width="180" height="270">
    </a>
    <figcaption class="wp-caption-text">
        <a title="Destination Weddings - Anguilla" href="/gallery/destination-weddings/anguilla.html">Anguilla</a>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

I put together this but it doesnt work why?

```
$(function() {
 var url = document.location.href;
    if (url.indexOf("chicago-weddings") > -1) {
    $(".carousel-link").removeClass("carousel-link-active");
    $(this).addClass("carousel-link-active");
    var tabid = $(this).data("tabid");
    $(".carousel-tab").fadeOut();
    $("#" + tabid).fadeIn();
    $(window).trigger("resize");
    $('#carousel1').addClass('selected');
}
 else if (url.indexOf("tented-weddings") > -1) {
    $(".carousel-link").removeClass("carousel-link-active");
    $(this).addClass("carousel-link-active");
    var tabid = $(this).data("tabid");
    $(".carousel-tab").fadeOut();
    $("#" + tabid).fadeIn();
    $(window).trigger("resize");
    $('#carousel2').addClass('selected');
}
 else if (url.indexOf("destination-weddings") > -1) {
    $(".carousel-link").removeClass("carousel-link-active");
    $(this).addClass("carousel-link-active");
    var tabid = $(this).data("tabid");
    $(".carousel-tab").fadeOut();
    $("#" + tabid).fadeIn();
    $(window).trigger("resize");
    $('#carousel3').addClass('selected');
}
 else if (url.indexOf("parties") > -1) {
    $(".carousel-link").removeClass("carousel-link-active");
    $(this).addClass("carousel-link-active");
    var tabid = $(this).data("tabid");
    $(".carousel-tab").fadeOut();
    $("#" + tabid).fadeIn();
    $(window).trigger("resize");
    $('#carousel4').addClass('selected');
}
 else if (url.indexOf("events") > -1) {
    $(".carousel-link").removeClass("carousel-link-active");
    $(this).addClass("carousel-link-active");
    var tabid = $(this).data("tabid");
    $(".carousel-tab").fadeOut();
    $("#" + tabid).fadeIn();
    $(window).trigger("resize");
    $('#carousel5').addClass('selected');
}
else {
    $(".carousel-link").removeClass("carousel-link-active");
    $(this).addClass("carousel-link-active");
    var tabid = $(this).data("tabid");
    $(".carousel-tab").fadeOut();
    $("#" + tabid).fadeIn();
    $(window).trigger("resize");
    $('#carousel1').addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please, tell us the what you've tried and what class you want to change, more data please.

Comment: I tried to add using something like below $(document).ready(function() {
  $('span:contains(Tented)').addClass('highlight'); ----- but it doesn't work because it doesn't check the page address. I need to somehow check the page address and add a class based on that but I don't know how.

Comment: Whichever gallery in the list is clicked on, needs to have background green and that particular the gallery is in needs to have a green text. This needs to change as I select different galleries.

Answer (score 1):

Study the example below and adjust to suit your need.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('span:contains(Tented)').addClass('highlight'); 

// The above adds adds the given class when Span contains the word Tented //
  
  });
```

```css
span  {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  }


.highlight {
  color: red;
  font-size: 72px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="carousel-link" data-tabid="carousel1">Chikago Wedding</span>
<span class="carousel-link" data-tabid="carousel1">Tented Weddings</span>
```

To check the page address do something like below

```
// Current URL hihglighter code starts here 
$(function() {
 var url = document.location.href;
    if (url.indexOf("about") > -1) {
    $('ul li:contains("About")').addClass('this-class');
}
 else if (url.indexOf("index") > -1) {
    $('ul li:contains:(Home)').addClass('home-tab');
}

else {
       // do what you like here
    }
});
```

**Note:** Contains is case sensitive.

Comment: I need an if statement because there are multiple tabs and what is open will change depending on the user's selection.

Comment: cool. Can I add class to two items at the same time with this code? like the tab itself and then tab's item in it ? Would I have to repeat this code twice then? $('ul li:contains("About")').addClass('this-class'); $('ul li:contains("About")').addClass('this-class'); ? and edit accordingly?

Comment: yes you can add class to two items at the same by just doing something like $('element1, element2').addClass('this-class');